# SharePoint-Search 2013 Query Transform keeps appending SPSPeople exclusion

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I'm trying to get FQL working in an out-of-the-box Enterprise Search Site Collection in on-premise SharePoint 2013, with no success.

Intended query behavior is to:
 - Accept and query search terms
 - Limit results to the current subdomain (https://teams.domain.com/...)
 - Exclude People from results

Our functioning KQL Query Transform is

```
{?{searchTerms} {?path:{QueryString.p}} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}
```

As instructed in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163973.aspx) I copied current Result Source (in Site Collection Administration) and modified the Query Transform to:

```
andnot((and({?{searchTerms}},{?path:{QueryString.p}})),(filter(contentclass:"urn:content-class:SPSPeople*")))
```

I tried other variations as well but none work.

**Even more puzzling to me** when I go from "Basics" tab to "Test" tab and click "Show more", the Query text box is ALWAYS appended with

```
-ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

Since it's not FQL formatted I figure that's why my template won't work. I've been at this all day now... Any suggestions what to do next? How do I get rid of that KQL suffix?

Comment: I tried to simplify... these work individually: **{?{searchTerms}}** KQL: **{?{searchTerms}} {?path:{QueryString.p}}** but still can't get any FQL format to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... I trusted the FQL Query Tranformation was correct and bypassed the "Launch Query Builder" button altogether, inputting the FQL into Query Transform text box.